# How do i split output of "who -m"command in linux?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I want to split output of who command and store output in variable

EX.

```
[root@ip ~]# who -m
root_user pts/1        2015-09-16 08:32 (windows-host.net)
```

I want to split this output like

```
var1 = root_user

var2 = 2015-09-16

var3 = 08:32

var4 = windows-host.net (This is hostname)
```

Comment: You want to split it using python or using bash script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
import re

text = "root_user pts/1        2015-09-16 08:32 (windows-host.net)"
var1, var2, var3, var4 = re.search(r'(.*?)\s.*?(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2})\s(\d{2}:\d{2})\s+\((.*)\)', text).groups()

print 'var1 =', var1
print 'var2 =', var2
print 'var3 =', var3
print 'var4 =', var4
```

Giving:

```
var1 = root_user
var2 = 2015-09-16
var3 = 08:32
var4 = windows-host.net
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
import os 

command = os.popen('who -m')
text = command.read()
text = text.strip()
list = text.split()

var1 = a[0]
var2 = a[2]
var3 = a[3]
var4 = a[4]
```

output:

```
>>> var1
'root_user'
>>> var2
'2015-09-16'
>>> var3
'08:32'
>>> var4
'(windows-host.net)'
```

However this is the easiest way to do that using Python.

And if you'd like to do that using bash script, try these commands:

```
var1=$(who -m | cut -f 1 -d ' ')
var2=$(who -m | cut -f 13 -d ' ')
var3=$(who -m | cut -f 14 -d ' ')
var4=$(who -m | cut -f 15 -d ' ')
```

Comment: You also split `2015-09-16 08:32`

Comment: @ozgur No, this script wouldn't do that.

Comment: I would add .strip() to os.popen('who -m').read() to clean up '\n'. Aside from that, your code is the easiest way to do it.

Comment: @alec_djinn Good idea, what do you think of this?

Comment: It's working on my Arch Linux(4.1.6-1).  And you can try @anubhava's script.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python

import os
command = os.popen('who -m')
text = command.read()
text = text.strip()
list = text.split()
print list[1]
print list[2]
print list[3]
print list[4]

Comment: replace `print list[1]` to `print list[0]`

Comment: Replace a with list in above code.
Ex. var1 = a[0] --> var1 = list[0]

Comment: @Kevin Guan That is also ok, but in general I prefer python over shell.

Answer (score 1):

In a BASH you can do this using built-in `read` and [`process substitution`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

```
IFS='( )' read var1 _ var2 var3 var4 _ < <(who -m)
```

`IFS='( )'` will set input field separators as one of the `(` or space or `)`.

Verify variables:

```
echo "[$var1][$var2][$var3][$var4]"
[root_user][2015-09-16][08:32][windows-host.net]
```